# Is there a theoretical reason why simple models perform better than complex models on time series forecasting tasks?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, regularization, bias-variance-tradeoff

Empirically, simple forecasting methods such as damped trend exponential smoothing, STL, or even  random walks typically outperform more complex models such as higher order ARIMA models or ML based approaches.

See for example the results of the M3 and M4 competitions.

Is this just an empirical result or is there a theoretical backing for this?

Is this just the ideas of parsimony and regularization writ large? Or is there a more detailed theoretical reason for this?

Comment: I think parsimony comes into this. With more complicated models, there are usually more parameters to estimate. Especially higher-order terms and their coefficients can be sensitive to subtleties in the (training) data set, which may be very different from those in other (testing) data sets. So overfitting by complex models is a real issue, and tests for significance of the overall model (F) and individual coefficients (t) should always be part of the exercise.

Comment: Occam’s razor maybe?

Comment: @DilipSarwate that's the point of my question: Is it just Occam's razor or is there something more explicit and specific going on?